# how to add offline countdown timer capabilities to add things (Lives, Points, etc.)

Tags: android, kotlin, time, timer

First time asking a question hopefully I did it right

Self-taught here so lots of questions been looking through other similar questions but haven't been able to find one that answers my question. I'm creating an Android app with a life system the user does something incorrectly they lose a life and the only way to get more lives is to wait or buy them with points earned. the only 2 problems I have is that

A) it doesn't countdown when the activity isn't accessed

B) it doesn't account for time elapsed time the user has closed the app to distribute the appropriate lives, the user should get 1 life per hour maxing out at 10

went through a bunch of youtube videos and other similar threads but haven't found an answer or well maybe haven't figured out how to properly utilize an answer if found.

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.CountDownTimer
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

class AdditionalLivesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        const val TOTAL_POINTS_KEY = "total_points"
        const val TOTAL_LIVES_KEY = "total_lives"
        const val MAX_LIVES = 10
        const val LIFE_RESTORE_TIME = 0.001 // in hours
        const val POINTS_PER_LIFE = 1000

    }

    private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
    private var totalPoints: Int = 0
    private var totalLives: Int = 0

    private lateinit var countDownTimer: CountDownTimer

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.additional_lives)


        val timerTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.timerTextView)
        timerTextView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        if (totalLives <= 9)
            timerTextView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("GamePreferences", MODE_PRIVATE)

        totalPoints = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_POINTS_KEY, 0)
        totalLives = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_LIVES_KEY, 0)

           val settingsButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.settingsButton)
        settingsButton.setOnClickListener {
        settingsButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#347B16"))
        saveGameState()
        val intent = Intent(this, MainMenuActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    totalPoints = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_POINTS_KEY, 0)
    totalLives = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_LIVES_KEY, 0)

    val pointsBuy = findViewById<Button>(R.id.pointsBuy)
    pointsBuy.setOnClickListener {
        if (totalPoints >= POINTS_PER_LIFE) {
            totalPoints -= POINTS_PER_LIFE
            totalLives += 1
            updatePointsTextView()
            saveGameState()
        }
    }

    updatePointsTextView()
    initializeLifeTimer()
}
private fun saveGameState() {
    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
    editor.putInt(TOTAL_POINTS_KEY, totalPoints)
    editor.putInt(TOTAL_LIVES_KEY, totalLives)
    editor.apply()
}

private fun updatePointsTextView() {
    val pointsTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.pointsTextView)
    val livesTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.scoreTextView)
    pointsTextView.text = "Points: $totalPoints"
    livesTextView.text = "Lives: $totalLives"
}

private fun initializeLifeTimer() {

    val timerTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.timerTextView)
    if (totalLives >= 10)
        timerTextView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    val millisUntilFinished = calculateMillisUntilNextLife()

    countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(millisUntilFinished.toLong(), 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            if (totalLives >= 10)
                timerTextView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            val hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)
            val minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) % 60
            val seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) % 60

            timerTextView.text = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            if (totalLives < MAX_LIVES) {
                totalLives += 1
                updatePointsTextView()
                saveGameState()
            }
            initializeLifeTimer()
        }
    }

    countDownTimer.start()
}

private fun calculateMillisUntilNextLife(): Double {
    val currentLives = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_LIVES_KEY, 0)
    val elapsedTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - sharedPreferences.getLong("timestamp", 0)

    val timeToRestoreLife = LIFE_RESTORE_TIME * 60 * 60 * 1000 // Convert to milliseconds
    val remainingMillisUntilNextLife = timeToRestoreLife - (elapsedTimeMillis % timeToRestoreLife)

    if (currentLives < MAX_LIVES && remainingMillisUntilNextLife.toInt() == timeToRestoreLife.toInt()) {
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.putLong("timestamp", System.currentTimeMillis())
        editor.apply()
    }

    return remainingMillisUntilNextLife
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    totalPoints = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_POINTS_KEY, 0)
    totalLives = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_LIVES_KEY, 0)
    updatePointsTextView()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    
}
}
```

made some adjustments and tried to switch to a notification approach tho no luck yet

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class AdditionalLivesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
companion object {
    const val TOTAL_POINTS_KEY = "total_points"
    const val TOTAL_LIVES_KEY = "total_lives"
    const val MAX_LIVES = 10
    const val POINTS_PER_LIFE = 1000
    const val LIFE_RESTORE_TIME = 1
}

private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
private var totalPoints: Int = 0
private var totalLives: Int = 0
private lateinit var timerTextView: TextView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.additional_lives)

    timerTextView = findViewById(R.id.timerTextView)
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("GamePreferences", MODE_PRIVATE)

    totalPoints = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_POINTS_KEY, 0)
    totalLives = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_LIVES_KEY, 0)

    if (totalLives <= 9) {
        timerTextView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        timerTextView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("GamePreferences", MODE_PRIVATE)

    totalPoints = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_POINTS_KEY, 0)
    totalLives = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_LIVES_KEY, 0)

    val settingsButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.settingsButton)
    settingsButton.setOnClickListener {
        settingsButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#347B16"))
        saveGameState()
        val intent = Intent(this, MainMenuActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    val pointsBuy = findViewById<Button>(R.id.pointsBuy)
    pointsBuy.setOnClickListener {
        if (totalPoints >= POINTS_PER_LIFE) {
            totalPoints -= POINTS_PER_LIFE
            totalLives += 1
            updatePointsTextView()
            saveGameState()
        }
    }

    updatePointsTextView()
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    registerReceiver(timerReceiver, IntentFilter("com.example.wordguessinggame.TIMER_UPDATE"))
    totalPoints = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_POINTS_KEY, 0)
    totalLives = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_LIVES_KEY, 0)
    updatePointsTextView()
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    unregisterReceiver(timerReceiver)
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    saveGameState()
}

private val timerReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val hours = intent.getLongExtra("hours", 0)
        val minutes = intent.getLongExtra("minutes", 0)
        val seconds = intent.getLongExtra("seconds", 0)

        // Update the timerTextView with the remaining time
        timerTextView.text = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
    }
}

private fun saveGameState() {
    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
    editor.putInt(TOTAL_POINTS_KEY, totalPoints)
    editor.putInt(TOTAL_LIVES_KEY, totalLives)
    editor.apply()
}

private fun updatePointsTextView() {
    val pointsTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.pointsTextView)
    val livesTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.scoreTextView)
    pointsTextView.text = "Points: $totalPoints"
    livesTextView.text = "Lives: $totalLives"
}
}
```

and used a service here

```
import android.app.AlarmManager
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.CountDownTimer
import android.os.IBinder
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import AdditionalLivesActivity.Companion.LIFE_RESTORE_TIME
import AdditionalLivesActivity.Companion.MAX_LIVES
import MainMenuActivity.Companion.TOTAL_LIVES_KEY
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
class LifeUpdateService : Service() {
private lateinit var alarmManager: AlarmManager
private lateinit var pendingIntent: PendingIntent
private lateinit var countDownTimer: CountDownTimer
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("GamePreferences", MODE_PRIVATE)

    alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
        this,
        0,
        Intent(this, LifeUpdateService::class.java),
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )
    val totalLives = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_LIVES_KEY, 0)
    val intervalMillis = 60 * 60 * 1000 // 1 hour in milliseconds


    alarmManager.setRepeating(
        AlarmManager.RTC,
        System.currentTimeMillis() + intervalMillis,
        intervalMillis.toLong(),
        pendingIntent
    )
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("GamePreferences", MODE_PRIVATE)
    var totalLives = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_LIVES_KEY, 0)
    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()

    if (totalLives < MAX_LIVES) {
        totalLives += 1
        editor.putInt(TOTAL_LIVES_KEY, totalLives)
        editor.apply()

        val resetTimer = true
        intent?.putExtra("reset_timer", resetTimer)

        // Show a notification to inform the user that a new life is available
        showLifeAvailableNotification()
    } else {
        val remainingMillisUntilNextLife = calculateMillisUntilNextLife()
        val hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(remainingMillisUntilNextLife.toLong())
        val minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(remainingMillisUntilNextLife.toLong()) % 60
        val seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(remainingMillisUntilNextLife.toLong()) % 60

        intent?.putExtra("hours", hours)
        intent?.putExtra("minutes", minutes)
        intent?.putExtra("seconds", seconds)

        // Provide feedback to the user about the remaining time using notifications or other means
        showRemainingTimeNotification(hours, minutes, seconds)
    }

    // Broadcast the intent to update the UI in the activity
    sendBroadcast(intent)

    // Start the timer
    startTimer()

    return START_STICKY
}

private fun stopTimer() {
    countDownTimer.cancel()
    countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(1, 1) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
        }
    }
}


private fun showLifeAvailableNotification() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channelId = "life_notification_channel"
        val channelName = "Life Notifications"
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, importance)
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    // Create the notification content
    val notificationId = 1
    val channelId = "life_notification_channel"
    val contentTitle = "New Life Available"
    val contentText = "You have a new life available. Keep playing!"
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this,
        0,
        Intent(this, AdditionalLivesActivity::class.java),
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )

    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
        .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
        .setContentText(contentText)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .build()

    // Show the notification
    val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification)
}

private fun showRemainingTimeNotification(remainingTime: Long, minutes: Long, seconds: Long) {
    val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    val channelId = "my_channel_id"
    val channelName = "My Channel"
    val contentTitle = "Next Life Available"
    val contentText = "Your next life will be available in $remainingTime ms"

    val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)

    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
        .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
        .setContentText(contentText)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .build()

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification)
}

private fun calculateMillisUntilNextLife(): Long {
    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("GamePreferences", MODE_PRIVATE)
    val currentLives = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_LIVES_KEY, 0)
    val elapsedTimeMillis =
        System.currentTimeMillis() - sharedPreferences.getLong("timestamp", 0)

    val timeToRestoreLife = LIFE_RESTORE_TIME * 60 * 60 * 1000 // Convert to milliseconds
    val additionalLives = (elapsedTimeMillis / timeToRestoreLife).toInt()

    if (additionalLives > 0 && currentLives < MAX_LIVES) {
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.putInt(TOTAL_LIVES_KEY, currentLives + additionalLives)
        editor.putLong("timestamp", System.currentTimeMillis())
        editor.apply()
    }

    return timeToRestoreLife - (elapsedTimeMillis % timeToRestoreLife)
}
private fun startTimer() {
    countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(Long.MAX_VALUE, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("GamePreferences", MODE_PRIVATE)
            val totalLives = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_LIVES_KEY, 0)

            // Check if the total lives reach the maximum
            if (totalLives >= MAX_LIVES) {
                // Stop the timer and return
                countDownTimer.cancel()
                return
            }

            // Calculate remaining time in hours, minutes, and seconds
            val hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)
            val minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) % 60
            val seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) % 60

            // Broadcast the timer updates to the AdditionalLivesActivity
            val intent = Intent("com.example.wordguessinggame.TIMER_UPDATE")
            intent.putExtra("hours", hours)
            intent.putExtra("minutes", minutes)
            intent.putExtra("seconds", seconds)
            sendBroadcast(intent)
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            // Timer finished
        }
    }

    countDownTimer.start()
}

override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
    return null
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)
    stopTimer()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Android apps don't run in the background as standard. If your app isn't on the screen, you should expect that it will be killed by the system to save resources.

If you want your app to continue doing work in the background, [there are a bunch of approaches depending on what you need to do](https://developer.android.com/guide/background). Broadly there are two types - running a *Service* which allows your app to continue running in the background (confusingly called a *foreground service* - it gives your app that foreground priority that keeps it alive), and various ways of scheduling work to be done, like using `WorkManager`, alarms, etc.

Foreground services are good for long-running work that needs to be happening while other things are happening with the device, e.g. media players (you're not typically looking at the media player app while listening to music). Scheduled work is good for running short-lived tasks while allowing your app to be killed, or doing updates at certain times whether your app is being used or not.

---

You could go for one of these approaches, and they do involve some work. But the question is, for your scenario, do you need them? I'd argue your app definitely *doesn't* need to be constantly running in the background here. You *could* schedule some update tasks to increment your lives at a certain time, and do whatever else (like showing a notification), but that might not be necessary either.

For a lot of apps, these updates don't need to happen *until the user is actually looking at the app*. Say I get a new life today at 5pm - when I open the app, it can check that "extra life" timestamp and the current time, and update if that time has passed. So if I open it before 5pm, I don't see an extra life, and if I open it after I do. So basically, you're checking the state *when the app returns to the foreground*, and nothing happens in the background at all.

If you *do* need notifications, then you actually do need to trigger that at a certain time, so you'd need some kind of scheduled work for that. You can combine the two though - schedule a task that shows a *"you got an extra life!"* notification at 5pm, and still handle the actual state update when the app opens. Cancel and reschedule your notification tasks as necessary when the user opens the app and does things.

---

Also it's worth saying that this stuff is open to user manipulation - editing the data you store, changing the clock etc. For an app involving real money, this stuff is probably all handled server-side - the server tells you how many lives you have, how long it is until you get another one etc. Notifications are probably pushed by the server too (although since they just go "hey extra life!" they're not important and you could just schedule them on the device itself, they can't affect the game state even if you did manipulate when they show up)

Comment: so if I need it to say that every 1 hour you gain a life I would need a clock running in the background to always be ticking down and then restarting to know how many lives were gained

Comment: I've never worked with a server so I'm not sure about that, also when researching I did read that user could manipulate it like that but wasn't sure how else to do it, so thats why I'm asking. Also thanks for the info that was very informative.

Comment: @GIANT No I'm saying you probably *don't* need anything running in the background at all, which is something you generally want to avoid unless absolutely necessary. You could do something like storing the timestamp of the next life - then when the app next runs, you work out how many hours have passed since that timestamp, add the lives to your count, and work out when the next life is due. Instead of watching and updating this state "live" in the background, you just "catch up" when the app returns to the foreground. Look at the old state, work out what the new state is, and go from there

Comment: ok, I was thinking of something similar ill look into some ways to try and do that. Thanks!

Comment: I edited my post with something that doesn't work attempting the notification way but I'd love some feedback on trying the other way either way works for me.

Comment: @GIANT if you want specific help on an implementation, you should post a new question with some info about the problem ("doesn't work" isn't very helpful!). As a general approach, using an alarm with a BroadcastReceiver to show a notification is fine, and using a Service to run your live timer is fine if you want to do that, but combining them will give you problems because of restrictions on starting background services (like I said, you want to avoid this where possible)

Comment: Personally I'd probably work out the state when the Activity opens, then cancel any pending alarms (which would also stop notifications showing up - you don't need them if you're looking at the app) and start a timer that updates the UI, the stored current lives etc. When the app goes into the background (e.g. in `onStop`) you'd cancel the timer, store any state you need to, and reschedule your notification alarms as appropriate. (Because the "going to the background" stuff happens here, the "coming to the foreground" has to happen in its partner method `onStart` - not `onCreate`)

Comment: sorry doesn't work wasn't exactly what I meant thanks for letting me know. I meant that the timerTextView is no longer being updated. with information but it's not pulling an error either. so im not sure where the disconnect is, it may be because of what you were saying

Comment: I also asked the question here, I believe as you said.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76442563/timer-and-notification-scripts-not-communicating-properly

Comment: I'm going to attempt to switch to a queuing system for lives.