# timer and notification scripts not communicating properly

Tags: android, kotlin, time, timer

Self-taught here so lots of questions been looking through other similar questions but haven't been able to find one that answers my question. I'm creating an Android app with a life system the user does something incorrectly they lose a life and the only way to get more lives is to wait or buy them with points earned. the only 2 problems I have is that

A) it doesn't countdown when the activity isn't accessed

B) it doesn't account for time elapsed time the user has closed the app to distribute the appropriate lives, the user should get 1 life per hour maxing out at 10

went through a bunch of youtube videos and other similar threads but haven't found an answer or well maybe haven't figured out how to properly utilize an answer if found.

i have 2 scripts ones a timer base script and ones a notification script, they are not talking to eachother properly. The service should update the timerTextView with the time information. Was

get them to conmmunicate properly and have the notifdications work properly.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class AdditionalLivesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
companion object {
    const val TOTAL_POINTS_KEY = "total_points"
    const val TOTAL_LIVES_KEY = "total_lives"
    const val MAX_LIVES = 10
    const val POINTS_PER_LIFE = 1000
    const val LIFE_RESTORE_TIME = 1
}

private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
private var totalPoints: Int = 0
private var totalLives: Int = 0
private lateinit var timerTextView: TextView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.additional_lives)

    timerTextView = findViewById(R.id.timerTextView)
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("GamePreferences", MODE_PRIVATE)

    totalPoints = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_POINTS_KEY, 0)
    totalLives = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_LIVES_KEY, 0)

    if (totalLives <= 9) {
        timerTextView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        timerTextView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("GamePreferences", MODE_PRIVATE)

    totalPoints = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_POINTS_KEY, 0)
    totalLives = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_LIVES_KEY, 0)

    val settingsButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.settingsButton)
    settingsButton.setOnClickListener {
        settingsButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#347B16"))
        saveGameState()
        val intent = Intent(this, MainMenuActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    val pointsBuy = findViewById<Button>(R.id.pointsBuy)
    pointsBuy.setOnClickListener {
        if (totalPoints >= POINTS_PER_LIFE) {
            totalPoints -= POINTS_PER_LIFE
            totalLives += 1
            updatePointsTextView()
            saveGameState()
        }
    }

    updatePointsTextView()
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    registerReceiver(timerReceiver, IntentFilter("com.example.wordguessinggame.TIMER_UPDATE"))
    totalPoints = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_POINTS_KEY, 0)
    totalLives = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_LIVES_KEY, 0)
    updatePointsTextView()
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    unregisterReceiver(timerReceiver)
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    saveGameState()
}

private val timerReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val hours = intent.getLongExtra("hours", 0)
        val minutes = intent.getLongExtra("minutes", 0)
        val seconds = intent.getLongExtra("seconds", 0)

        // Update the timerTextView with the remaining time
        timerTextView.text = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
    }
}

private fun saveGameState() {
    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
    editor.putInt(TOTAL_POINTS_KEY, totalPoints)
    editor.putInt(TOTAL_LIVES_KEY, totalLives)
    editor.apply()
}

private fun updatePointsTextView() {
    val pointsTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.pointsTextView)
    val livesTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.scoreTextView)
    pointsTextView.text = "Points: $totalPoints"
    livesTextView.text = "Lives: $totalLives"
}
}
```

and here is the service script

```
import android.app.AlarmManager
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.CountDownTimer
import android.os.IBinder
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
AdditionalLivesActivity.Companion.LIFE_RESTORE_TIME
AdditionalLivesActivity.Companion.MAX_LIVES
MainMenuActivity.Companion.TOTAL_LIVES_KEY
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

class LifeUpdateService : Service() {
private lateinit var alarmManager: AlarmManager
private lateinit var pendingIntent: PendingIntent
private lateinit var countDownTimer: CountDownTimer

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("GamePreferences", MODE_PRIVATE)

    alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
        this,
        0,
        Intent(this, LifeUpdateService::class.java),
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )
    val totalLives = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_LIVES_KEY, 0)
    val intervalMillis = 60 * 60 * 1000 // 1 hour in milliseconds


    alarmManager.setRepeating(
        AlarmManager.RTC,
        System.currentTimeMillis() + intervalMillis,
        intervalMillis.toLong(),
        pendingIntent
    )
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("GamePreferences", MODE_PRIVATE)
    var totalLives = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_LIVES_KEY, 0)
    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()

    if (totalLives < MAX_LIVES) {
        totalLives += 1
        editor.putInt(TOTAL_LIVES_KEY, totalLives)
        editor.apply()

        val resetTimer = true
        intent?.putExtra("reset_timer", resetTimer)

        // Show a notification to inform the user that a new life is available
        showLifeAvailableNotification()
    } else {
        val remainingMillisUntilNextLife = calculateMillisUntilNextLife()
        val hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(remainingMillisUntilNextLife.toLong())
        val minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(remainingMillisUntilNextLife.toLong()) % 60
        val seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(remainingMillisUntilNextLife.toLong()) % 60

        intent?.putExtra("hours", hours)
        intent?.putExtra("minutes", minutes)
        intent?.putExtra("seconds", seconds)

        // Provide feedback to the user about the remaining time using notifications or other means
        showRemainingTimeNotification(hours, minutes, seconds)
    }

    // Broadcast the intent to update the UI in the activity
    sendBroadcast(intent)

    // Start the timer
    startTimer()

    return START_STICKY
}

private fun stopTimer() {
    countDownTimer.cancel()
    countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(1, 1) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
        }
    }
}


private fun showLifeAvailableNotification() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channelId = "life_notification_channel"
        val channelName = "Life Notifications"
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, importance)
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    // Create the notification content
    val notificationId = 1
    val channelId = "life_notification_channel"
    val contentTitle = "New Life Available"
    val contentText = "You have a new life available. Keep playing!"
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this,
        0,
        Intent(this, AdditionalLivesActivity::class.java),
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )

    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
        .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
        .setContentText(contentText)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .build()

    // Show the notification
    val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification)
}

private fun showRemainingTimeNotification(remainingTime: Long, minutes: Long, seconds: Long) {
    val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    val channelId = "my_channel_id"
    val channelName = "My Channel"
    val contentTitle = "Next Life Available"
    val contentText = "Your next life will be available in $remainingTime ms"

    val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)

    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
        .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
        .setContentText(contentText)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .build()

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification)
}

private fun calculateMillisUntilNextLife(): Long {
    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("GamePreferences", MODE_PRIVATE)
    val currentLives = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_LIVES_KEY, 0)
    val elapsedTimeMillis =
        System.currentTimeMillis() - sharedPreferences.getLong("timestamp", 0)

    val timeToRestoreLife = LIFE_RESTORE_TIME * 60 * 60 * 1000 // Convert to milliseconds
    val additionalLives = (elapsedTimeMillis / timeToRestoreLife).toInt()

    if (additionalLives > 0 && currentLives < MAX_LIVES) {
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.putInt(TOTAL_LIVES_KEY, currentLives + additionalLives)
        editor.putLong("timestamp", System.currentTimeMillis())
        editor.apply()
    }

    return timeToRestoreLife - (elapsedTimeMillis % timeToRestoreLife)
}
private fun startTimer() {
    countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(Long.MAX_VALUE, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("GamePreferences", MODE_PRIVATE)
            val totalLives = sharedPreferences.getInt(TOTAL_LIVES_KEY, 0)

            // Check if the total lives reach the maximum
            if (totalLives >= MAX_LIVES) {
                // Stop the timer and return
                countDownTimer.cancel()
                return
            }

            // Calculate remaining time in hours, minutes, and seconds
            val hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)
            val minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) % 60
            val seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) % 60

            // Broadcast the timer updates to the AdditionalLivesActivity
            val intent = Intent("com.example.wordguessinggame.TIMER_UPDATE")
            intent.putExtra("hours", hours)
            intent.putExtra("minutes", minutes)
            intent.putExtra("seconds", seconds)
            sendBroadcast(intent)
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            // Timer finished
        }
    }

    countDownTimer.start()
}

override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
    return null
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)
    stopTimer()
}
}
```